# Jquery - Invalid label error

Tags: jquery

i get the error

```
invalid label
 {"ok" : 1, "msg" : "Uh, we had a sligh...ne here now, thank you. How are you?"}
```

**my js code**

```
   $.ajax({
        url:"http://my.doomain.com:27080/_hello",
        success:function(data)
        {
          alert('Load was performed. '+data+'');
        },
        dataType:'jsonp',
        error:function()
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

PS: I use the rest api from mongo.db (sleepy mongoose)

Comment: I just read that someone had a similar problem but had to repair their URL: http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3932711.htm. You may want to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the JSON string in parenthesis as suggested here: [Solving the Invalid Label Error with JSON](http://willcode4beer.com/tips.jsp?set=jsonInvalidLabel)